# I am getting a failed build while running my project

Tags: flutter

I just upgraded my Android Studio and flutter SDK. When I try running my flutter project I keep getting this error below. I am using `flutter_paystack: ^1.0.5+1` package.

```
Parameter format not correct -
e: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_paystack-1.0.5+1\android\src\main\kotlin\co\paystack\flutterpaystack\FlutterPaystackPlugin.kt: (48, 62): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected
e: C:\src\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_paystack-1.0.5+1\android\src\main\kotlin\co\paystack\flutterpaystack\MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt: (19, 37): Type mismatch: inferred type is BinaryMessenger? but BinaryMessenger was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_paystack:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Please what might be the cause

Comment: I am facing the very same error with flutter version 3.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

package `flutter_paystack: 1.0.5+1` not work on flutter 3

try change dependency of `flutter_paystack 1.0.5+1` in `pubspec.yaml` to:

```
flutter_paystack:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/definitelyme/flutter_paystack.git
      ref: a4a33c3dd0a12f46d655a2e63d11e9f20ba82d01
```

Comment: Publishable packages can't have 'git' dependencies.
Try adding a 'publish_to: none' entry to mark the package as not for publishing or remove the git dependency.

Comment: I am using uni_payments, so I can't specify a version because paystack is included in it

Comment: I am using flutter 3.0.5. After updating the reference as proposed here, I still get the same issue. Has anyone successfully tried this fix in 3.0.5?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `android/build.gradle` file and update your **Kotlin** version hope its help to you.

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am already using ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10', which still gives me the error above.

Comment: try to change `flutter_paystack` version

Comment: change flutter_paystack to what version precisely?

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a problem with the Flutter version 3.

The best bet you have is to downgrade your flutter to version 2.x.x

This might conflict with other plugins you're using(like I experienced).

So you might as an alternative. Try embedding paystack payment in a webview. Create a web page, integrate paystack. Call that web page in a webview embedded in the app.

It might even be better if you're looking for extra payment options like bank transfer which isn't available on the flutter app plugin.